# Retrieving the product published field

Tags: 8, nodes, commerce

Within a node template I can retrieve the status of the published flag by calling the code: `node.isPublished()`

How do I retrieve the status of the published flag within a commerce product...

I've tried:

```
product.isPublished()
product.status
product.published
```

But I can't seem to get it to print. I've tried to look through the core code where status seems to be the key, but no luck, plus api.drupalcommerce.org is down.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IIRC `product` is the content render array, you probably want to look at `elements['#commerce_product'].status`

Comment: @Clive how would I access that from the product variable, product.elements['#commerce_product'].status?

Comment: Assuming you're in `theme_commerce_product` (standard entity view for commerce product) it's just `elements['#commerce_product'].status`

Answer (score 1):

`{% if product_entity.status.value == 0 %}
  {%
    set classes = [
    'is-unpublished'
    ]
  %}
{% endif %}
<article{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
..
</article>`